# How to get the value from data table and display in html table using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json

```
Private Sub btnDisplayOrder_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplayOrder.Click
    Try
        Dim aID As String = result.Value
        Dim aCdt As Date = Date.Parse(dt.Value.ToString())

        BillDetails = objOrdersData.gblstbdt(aID, aCdt)

        JSONBillDetails = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(BillDetails)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString(), MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel, "Error")
    End Try

End Sub
```

This is my aspx button click. BillDetails  is a datatable . In my data table i have ReferenceNo,BankResponse and StatusID. 
My Problem is : BankResponse  is a json string . Like this

```
   {"MID":"S49532106",
    "ORDERID":"06OpjcIJ",
      "TXNAMOUNT":"1.00",
       "CURRENCY":"INR",
       "TXNID":"324016",
       "BANKTXNID":"5159",
       "STATUS":"TXN_SUCCESS"}
```

How can i display the details in a html table. 
I want to display Refno BankDetails and Status id in a table. In the bank details column i want to display the fields like :" MId:001 , Status:Success "

```
 BillDetails = objOrdersData.gblstbdt(aID, aCdt)
```

From this line i got a datatable with data. In that I have a field Name as BankResponse . This field value is a json string. How can i get this json string from a data table?

My JSONBillDetails is like this:

```
{"UID":"62a2a9e0-ebe4b285b3","ReferenceNo":"0pjcIJ",

"BankResponse":"{"MID":"004106","ORDERID":"00pjcIJ",
 "TXNAMOUNT":"1.00",
 "CURRENCY":"INR",
 "TXNID":"34016","BANKTXNID":"659",
 "STATUS":"TXN_SUCCESS","RESPCODE":"01","RESPMSG":"Txn Successful.",
 "TXNDATE":"2017-01-28  12:03:55.0",
 "GATEWAYNAME":"WALLET","BANKNAME":"","PAYMENTMODE":"PPI",
 "CHECKSUMHASH":"mYpxxKD0bMYG7ZNUJzTP+"}",

  "StatusID":1,"CreatedDate":"2017-01-28T17:22:47","MerchantUID":"1aafc521-9e9a-481b4b2","EasyOrderBillsUID":"62d24-93223f09777d",
   "EOBguid":"62dbe07-9424-93223f09777d"}
```

This is not a good json string. "BankResponse":"{"MID":"0".....}"" this portion has a extra double quotes. so i canot be convert this to a json object.

What is the problem in my code?

Comment: What you have tried and what problems did you face in doing that? Share your code.

Comment: I got an error message like this : unexpected token M in json at position 92

Comment: parse your JSON, using `JSON.parse()`, `JSON.parse(your_object)`

Comment: If i convert my BankResponse field as normal string it working fine.

Comment: $scope.BillDetails = JSON.parse(BillDetails); yes I parse my json string. this line shows the error message

Comment: To convert obj to string, u should use, `JSON.stringify($scope.BillDetails)`, but I don't understand how u will display string in the view..